# Шаблон фабрика Javascript

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования, абстрактная-фабрика

разбираюсь с шаблоном фабрика(простая фабрика,фабричный метод, абстрактная фабрика) правильно ли я его понял?
Абстрактная фабрика насколько я понял,это больше одного метода,а реализация схожая с фабричным методом.

```
/* simple factory */

class Bouquet {
    create(price){
        if(price < 5000) {
            return new TulipsBouquet();
        }
        return new RosesBouquet();
    }
}

class RosesBouquet {
}

class TulipsBouquet {
}

const bouquetFactory = new Bouquet();

const cheap = bouquetFactory.create(1000);
const expensive = bouquetFactory.create(5000);

/* factory method */

class Bouquet {
    wither(){
        throw {name: 'override', message: 'need to override method wither'}
    }

    create(price){
        if(price < 5000) {
            return new TulipsBouquet();
        }
        return new RosesBouquet();
    }
}

class RosesBouquet extends Bouquet{
    wither(){
        console.log('7 day');
    }
}

class TulipsBouquet extends Bouquet{
    wither(){
        console.log('2 day');
    }
}

/* abstract factory */

class Bouquet {
    wither(){
        throw {name: 'override', message: 'need to override method wither'}
    }

    getBouquetLength() {
        throw {name: 'override', message: 'need to override method getBouquetLength'}
    }

    getBouquetPaper() {
        throw {name: 'override', message: 'need to override method getBouquetPaper'}
    }

    create(price){
        if(price < 5000) {
            return new TulipsBouquet();
        }
        return new RosesBouquet();
    }
}

class RosesBouquet extends Bouquet{
   ...
}

class TulipsBouquet extends Bouquet{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно причем здесь код. Задавали похожий вопрос тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5026/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Код это то как я понял различие между фабрикой, методом и абстрактной.Вопрос правильно или нет?

Comment: с фабричным методом согласен. С абстрактной фабрикой не уверен, абстрактная фабрика это фабрика фабрик. Реализуйте фабрику, после реализуйте по тому же принципу фабрику фабрик, это и будет абстрактной фабрикой