# зачем нужен паттерн фабрика

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Зачем нужен паттерн фабрика? Насколько я понял, фабрика принимает на вход некое значение, по которому возможно определить объект какого класса фабрика должна вернуть. Все эти возвращаемые классы являются потомками некого суперкласса или реализуют общий интерфейс. Внутри фабрики по сути обычный switch case (или что то подобное) который выбирает какой объект создать с помощью конструктора new.

И в чем профит такого подхода? В интернете я находил примеры из разряда того, что фабрика позволяет расширять систему, позволят использовать разные объекты в одном коде и т.д. Но это же все по сути обычный полиморфизм. Т.е. если я создам интерфейс или суперкласс и пару наследников, то какой профит может дать фабрика? Расширяемость, универсальность и т.д. обеспечивает полиморфизм. в чем радость писать фабрика.создайКласс(класТип1), а не new класТип1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет паттерна Фабрика. Вы, вероятно, пишете о Фабричном методе (другое его название (внезапно!) Конструктор). Профит от его использования в том, что ваши классы знают только про один интерфейс конструктора, а не про все возможные.

Допустим вы описали интерфейс `Средство_индивидуальной_мобильности` и классы `Электросмокат` и `Моноколесо`.
Для создания самоката нужны два колеса, для моноколеса -- одно. В своей библиотеке `Новые_правила_дорожного_движения`
вы бы не хотели знать сколько колёс нужно для создания этих средств индивидуальной мобильности. Но вы бы хотели иметь возможность их
инстанцировать. Как быть? Надо описать единый интерфейс конструктора! Это и будет шаблон Фабричный метод.
Вы получаете на вход некий метод (допустим совсем не требующий аргументов) и вызываете его для получения экземпляров средств индивидуальной мобильности.
Как именно метод их создаст вы совсем не думаете, и если в 2020 изобретут летающие скейты, то вам не надо будет переписывать ваши Новые правила дорожного движения.

Очевидно, что писать `фабрика.создайКласс(класТип1)` неверно. Надо писать `фабрика.создайНеизвестныйМнеКлассИзвестногоМнеИнтерфейса()`.

Answer (score 2):

Паттерн фабрики относительно сложный и имеет пару разновидностей. Его применяют в трудных ситуациях, поэтому подобрать лаконичный и адекватный (с точки зрения пользы) пример затруднительно.

Основная идея в том, что имеется несколько классов (с общим родителем/интерфейсом), объекты которых должны создаваться (возможно с большой логикой инициализации) и использоваться где-то дальше, но какие-то их типы и параметры уже известны, а какие-то появятся потом. В соответствии с этой информацией создаётся объект(ы) фабрики, который передаётся в другие этапы, логические части программы. Там фабрики уже получают остальные параметры и строят нужные объекты. То есть, применяются фабрики с целью абстрагирования, инкапсуляции, делегирования ответственности.

Важно отметить, что фабрики создаются "вручную": можно выбрать любой нужный тип фабрики и задать любые их настройки. В дальнейшем пайплайне фабрики вызываются кодом, который об их типах ничего не знает, обращается ко всем фабрикам одинаково, через единый интерфейс.

Про разновидности. Когда класс фабрики один, то это называется шаблоном "Фабричный метод". Когда их много и они наследуется от общего абстрактного класса, то это шаблоном "Абстрактная фабрика".

---

Допустим, мы разрабатываем симулятор политических действий. Для этого нужны объекты правительств. Но они зависят от идеологий и каких-то своих параметров (это фабрики и их аргументы), а также параметров модели (то, что будет подаваться готовым фабрикам на вход).

В данном случае объект правительства будет тем, что нужно получить в итоге (парламент/президент). В роли фабрики будут выступать экземпляры классов-идеологий, которые принимают на вход какие-то параметры, специфические для этих идеологий. А в итоге это всё передаётся в объект модели, там у фабрик вызывается общий метод с финальными параметрами (год моделируемых событий), и уже создаются итоговые объекты правительств.

Далее пример абстрактной фабрики на Питоне, немного громоздкий, но фабрики только так и применяются. Однако в целом код простой:

```py
class Government:
    def __init__(self, member_count):
        raise AttributeError('Not Implemented!')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Какое-то правительство'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

class Parliament(Government):
    def __init__(self, member_count, title=None):
        self.member_count = member_count
        self.title = 'Парламент' if title is None else title

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s из %s человек' % (self.title, self.member_count)

class President(Government):
    def __init__(self, reign_years, title=None):
        self.reign_years = reign_years
        self.title = 'Президент' if title is None else title

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s на срок %s лет' % (self.title, self.reign_years)


# Абстрактная фабрика
class Ideology:
    def __init__(self):
        raise AttributeError('Not Implemented!')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Какая-то идеология'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def create_goverment(self, year):
        # Сам фабричный метод
        raise AttributeError('Not Implemented!')

class Democracy(Ideology):
    def __init__(self, radical):
        self.radical = radical

    def create_goverment(self, year):
        years = 6 if year < 1990 else 4
        title = 'Президент'
        if self.radical:
            years *= 100
            title = 'Монарх'
        return President(years, title)

class Socialism(Ideology):
    def __init__(self, western=True):
        self.western = western

    def create_goverment(self, year):
        if not self.western and year >= 1991:
            parliament_title = 'Совет Федерации'
        else:
            parliament_title = 'Парламент'

        parliament_member_count = 10
        if year > 1800:
            parliament_member_count = 30
        if not self.western:
            parliament_member_count *= 2
        return Parliament(parliament_member_count, parliament_title)


class Model:
    def __init__(self, ideologies, year=1800):
        # Создаём из фабрик объекты через единый интерфейс
        self.governments = [x.create_goverment(year=year) for x in ideologies]

    def process(self):
        raise AttributeError('Not Implemented!')

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(['\t Модель правительств:'] + list(map(str, self.governments)))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Создаём фабрики со специфическими для них параметрами
    ideologies = (
        Democracy(radical=True),
        Democracy(radical=False),
        Socialism(western=True),
        Socialism(western=False),
    )
    # Передаём дальше
    m = Model(ideologies, year=1995)
    print(m)


### Вывод такой:
#     Модель правительств:
# Монарх на срок 400 лет
# Президент на срок 4 лет
# Парламент из 30 человек
# Совет Федерации из 60 человек

## PS: пример взят из воздуха и на полит.корректность совсем не претендует
```

В реальных задачах код ещё крупнее, зато применение фабрик в них ещё логичнее и полезнее.

Кстати, в Питоне зачастую у классов-фабрик удобно и логично переопределять метод `__call__`. Помимо лаконичности, это позволяет одинаково работать как со своими фабриками, так и с конструкторами классов (ведь Питоне классы являются callable-объектами, возвращающими итоговые объекты, то есть, классы являются фабриками).

Полезные ссылки:

- ruSO: [Фабричный метод и абстрактная фабрика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/5026/198251)
- Wiki: [Фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))
- Wiki: [Абстрактная фабрика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

На Википедии есть ещё примеры кода по разным языкам, а также диаграммы классов, что поможет глубже понять эти шаблоны проектирования.

Comment: "Там фабрики уже получают остальные параметры и строят нужные объекты" и это напоминает скорее Строителя.

Answer (score 1):

Данный паттерн удобно использовать, когда результатом вызова становиться указатель на некую абстракцию, при чем по факту фабрика скрывает что и как создает и инициализирует, а самое главное, она не дает для вызывающего кода ни каких знаний про реализацию.

По факту у Вас должна быть абстракция, того что Вы хотели бы делать, и не сколько реализацией этой абстракции. Фабрика должна создавать и инициализировать нужную Вам реализацию, и возвращать абстрактный указатель на созданный объект.

Так же данный паттерн позволяет собрать в единое место, весь Ваш код отвевающий за создание объектов.

Answer (score 1):

В классической литературе не описан паттерн *Фабрика*.

В книге GoF описаны *Абстрактная фабрика* и *Фабричный метод*. В интернете можно найти *Статическую фабрику* и *Простую фабрику*.

Похоже, что вы спрашиваете про *Простую фабрику*. Вот варианты, когда она может пригодиться.

#### Десериализация

Мы берём сложный объект и сохраняем его, например, в виде GeoJSON. На другой стороне мы пытаемся восстановить исходный объект.

```
{ "type": "Point", 
  "coordinates": [30, 10]
}

{ "type": "LineString", 
  "coordinates": [
    [30, 10], [10, 30], [40, 40]
  ]
}
```

Здесь приходится по свойству `type` создавать объекты разных типов. Эту функцию
можно взять на себя фабрика. В языка с поддержкой рефлексии или с динамической
типизацией это нетрудно. В таком языке как С++ возможно придётся сделать `switch`, о 
котором вы писали.

#### Управление временем жизни

Этот сценарий часто встречается в рамках IoC- 
контейнеров, когда вы пытаетесь сделать что-то не совсем стандартное с инверсией 
зависимостей. Скажем, у вас есть объект репозиторий, который не имеет
состояния. Его можно зарегистрировать в IoC как singleton, и он будет существовать в 
единственном экземпляре всё время работы программы. Каждому его методу потребуется 
connection к базе данных, а connection создаётся в начале web-запроса и освобождается
в конце. Тогда фабрика подключений можно создавать или возвращать уже созданный в 
рамках запроса экземпляр. Вот как это может выглядеть в Entity Framework:

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    private readonly DbContextFactory _dbContextFactory;

    public OrderRepository(DbContextFactory dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public Order GetById(int id)
    {
        using (var dbContext = _dbContextFactory.Create())
        {
            . . .
        }
    }
}
```

#### Много параметров конструктора

Если вы создаёте сложный объект с большим количеством параметров, код усложняется. Часто бывает, что все эти параметры не нужны. Тогда фабрика может скрыть от вас неважные с ваше точки зрения параметры, заполняя их самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Паттерн простая фабрика применяют в случае, если в коде у вас происходит создание объекта того или иного класса в зависимости от условий. Если это происходит только в одном месте - то стоит вспомнить первый принцип [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) - Single responsibility (единственной ответственности) и вынести кусок кода создания объектов в новый отдельный класс. Если несколько раз - то профит тем более очевиден в меньшем количестве строк кода (и в случае если у вас появится новое условие `if (type='d')`, то его нужно будет добавить только в одном месте - в фабрике).

```
    /* some code */

    // classes A,B,C extends interface IType
    IType object;
    if (type = 'a') {
        object = new A();
    } elseif (type = 'b') {
        object = new B();
    } elseif (type = 'c') {
        object = new C();
    }

    /* another code */
```